# (Basic Scaling) Will App Engine shut down an app that's still busy handling a request if the idle timeout is reached?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, autoscaling

Google describes basic scaling like this:

[image]

I don't really have any other choice, as I'm using a B1 instance, so automatic scaling is not allowed.

That raises the question though, if I have an endpoint that takes a variable amount of time (could be minutes, could be hours), and I basically have to set an `idle_timeout`, will App Engine calculate `idle_timeout` from the time the request was made in the first place or when the app is done handling the request?

If the former is right, then it feels a bit unfair to have to guess how long requests will take when thread activity is a usable indicator of whether or not to initiate shutdown of an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are mixing up two different terms.

[idle_timeout](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#idle_timeout) is the time that the instance will wait before shutting down after receiving its last request

[Request timeout](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/how-instances-are-managed#timeout) is the amount of time that App Engine will wait for the return of a request from your app

As per the documentation:

> Requests can run for up to 24 hours. A manually-scaled instance can
> choose to handle /_ah/start and execute a program or script for many
> hours without returning an HTTP response code. Task queue tasks can
> run up to 24 hours.

Comment: you're probably right but "receiving" and "completing" have totally separate implications